# jQuery Maskedinput plugin incorrect focus

Tags: jquery, maskedinput

I am using jQuery 1.9.0, jQuery-ui-1.10.0, and the Maskedinput 1.3.1 plugin from Digitalbush.com.

My phone number mask is as follows:

```
$('[ID*="strSponsorContactPhone"]').mask("(999)999-9999? x99999", { placeholder: " " });
```

My date mask is as follows:

```
$('[ID*="strEventDateEnd"]').mask("9999-99-99", { placeholder: " " });
```

This seems to work as it's supposed to except that when the input field gets focus either by tabbing to it or by clicking directly in it, the initial cursor position is one character to the right, leaving a blank digit for the first character. When the user leaves the field (loses focus), the position is corrected. This is somewhat disconcerting to users.

This happens in both IE8 and Firefox 19.0.

Any idea if this is common and/or why this is happening?

**UPDATE**:  Further information, this seems to happen in both VB.NET pages served with IIS *and* PHP pages served with Apache.  Frankly, I didn't expect a difference but I had to try and I felt it necessary to add the results here.

Comment: Isnt that' space comming from the placeholder? have you tried using `{placeholder: ""}`?

Comment: No, if I use `{placeholder: ""}` the field displays "()- x" and the cursor starts immediately after the "()".

Comment: Just for clarification, I use `{placeholder: " "}` to replace the _ (underscore character) in the input display mask with a " " (single space).  I get the same behavior if I use "" (nothing) or if I simply leave it as the default underscore.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue